# WPF application difference in behavior for touch versus mouse/stylus

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, data-binding, focus, wpf-controls

I have an application that shows the user a message through a messagebox. After the user clicks okay, it 
restores the focus to an ItemsControl above in the visual tree.

The weird behavior I'm running into: using your finger, you have to press twice on any button after the message box is closed.
The first finger press can be literally anywhere on the screen. It seems like a focus issue but we restored the focus already.
Using the mouse or a stylus only requires 1 click for a button to work after a message box is closed.

Has anyone run into a problem like this before? I don't have much experience with WPF.

Here's the message box being shown and how the focus is set afterwards. It'll go into the first if statement.

```
// Save the element with focus.
UIElement uiElement = Keyboard.FocusedElement as UIElement;

// show message box
using (new DisposableCursor(Cursors.Arrow))
{
    result = window.Show(type, title, message, buttons);
}

// Check if element still has focus after displaying the message box.
if (uiElement != null && uiElement != Keyboard.FocusedElement) 
{
    // Go up the visual tree to try to set the focus to a parent element.
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        uiElement = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(uiElement) as UIElement;

        if (uiElement == null)
        {
            break;
        }

        if (uiElement.Focus())
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the focus was a red herring. There was no event handler for TouchDown, even though there were handlers for StylusUp and Click. As to why that caused the first finger press to not register, I don't know. From what I read, Touch events should be promoted to Click events, so it should have worked fine.